# GitHub API authorization works with node-fetch v2 but not with v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, authorization, github-api, node-fetch

I have the following fetch request that works fine with node-fetch v2.6.0:

```
const url = "https://github.developer.mycompany.io/api/v3/search/code?q=%3Cnxt+extension%3Ats+extension%3Ahtml+repo%3Aawesome/repo&per_page=100"

const options = {
  agent: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Basic toookenn',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    Cookie: 'yummycookie'
  }
}    

response = await fetch(url, options);
const data = await response.json();
```

But when I update to the current node-fetch v3.2.9 the authorization fails and I only get the HTML of the login page as response.
I could not find any changes regarding headers or authorization in the [node-fetch v2 to v3 upgrade guide](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/HEAD/docs/v3-UPGRADE-GUIDE.md).

Does anyone know what's the problem here?